# For loop with an array in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, script, array

I want to use `for` loop with an array. I using the following command for this:

```
#! /bin/bash
rm -f /orch/list

arrayVM=($(cat /orch/servers | grep $1 | awk '{print $1}'))
for i in $arrayVM
do
        echo ${arrayVM[$i]}>>list
done
```

But when I check the `list` file I see only the first element of `arrayVM` array. What's wrong with my command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The principle error is that `for i in $arrayVM` sets `i` to the first element in `arrayVM`, since there is no index. I am surprised that this does not give an error on the `echo` command, unless the first array element is numeric.

What you need is the iterative form of `for`:-

```
for (( i=0; i<${#arrayVM[*]}; ++i ))
do
    echo ${arrayVM[$i]}>>list
done
```

However, this is unnecessarily long-winded: much simpler is:-

```
for e in "${arrayVM[@]}"
do
    echo $e>>list
done
```

This assigns `e` to each element in turn, without enumerating them.

In the light of Fedorqui's answer, if `arrayVM` is not needed elsewhere, then there is a much simpler way to create the list file:-

```
cat /orch/servers | grep $1 | awk '{print $1}' >/orch/list
```

Or, since the `cat` is [unnecessary](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html):-

```
grep $1 </orch/servers | awk '{print $1}' >/orch/list
```

Comment: Thanks. I removed parentheses of define row. arrayVM=$(cat ......) and it works.

Comment: Removing the parentheses makes `arrayVM` a long string with embedded new-lines if it is previously undeclared; if it is already declared as an array, then it will become a single-element array, and the element will be the long string. Run `declare -p arrayVM` after the assignment in each case to verify this.

Comment: I should have added that making `arrayVM` a long string will work, but not in the way you might expect.

Comment: My edit crossed with the questioner's comment on @fedorqui's answer, making my assumption invalid, but I shall leave it in place for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the data to be stored in an array but you also want to use every record for other things, you can loop normally through the data with a [process substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30870094/1983854):

```
while IFS= read -r value _;
do
        echo "$value" >> list
done < <(grep "$1" /orch/servers)
```

With `read -r value _` we are storing the first field in `$value` and the rest in the throw away variable `$_`.

Comment: I assumed in my answer that the array would be needed elsewhere. Otherwise, `cat /orch/servers | grep $1 | awk '{print $1}'>/orch/list` would suffice.